# Adjusting RGB on PIL ImageGrab Module Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a screencast script with ImageGrab but I am getting wired blue color images

[image: Image Sample]

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import ImageGrab

    out = cv2.VideoWriter('record.avi', 2, 8.0, (1366, 768)) 
    while (True):
       img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1366, 768)) # x, y, w, h
       img_np = np.array(img)
       frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       out.write(img_np)
       cv2.imshow("Recorder", frame)
       key = cv2.waitKey(1)
       if key == 27:
          break
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: First of all: check what's returned by grab. Shape and dtypes. PIL or Pillow? Windows / MacOSX? And if you are already using opencv: this lib probably has the same functionality!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
vid.write(RGB_img)
```

This will work.